# Distributed tracing from the mobile application to the backend and include custom info

Tags: trace, grpc, linkerd, opentracing

We have Android and iOS (Objective-C) mobile applications.
Our Business Intelligence team is interested in receiving the following parameters with each data event:

- the app version
- the user session id

We use gRPC for both the mobile-backend communication and also for communicating between the different microservices on the backend.

I am considering sending this information using open tracing spans that are started on the mobile app and pass the app version and session id trough the **Baggage**.

Can anyone advise if open tracing is suitable for this scenario or if there is a better alternative?

We are also considering using LinkerD on the backend

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure baggage is really what you want. [OpenTracing also offers the possibility of adding tags to a span](https://github.com/opentracing/specification/blob/master/specification.md#the-opentracing-data-model), which would probably be sufficient for your use-case.

A baggage item is sent downstream along with the span context, whereas a tag is "local" to a span. If you *need* access to the app version on a span downstream, then you indeed have to use a baggage item, but if all you need is to have the version information within the span, you should just tag it.

About OpenTracing being suitable or not: I'd say that's exactly the purpose of OpenTracing. Not only you'll potentially get "automatic" spans from the frameworks you are using (using the ["framework integrations"](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib)), but also you can relate that to your business information. We have an example on Hawkular APM where we add both ["operational" and "business" data to traces](https://github.com/hawkular/hawkular-apm/tree/master/examples/vertx-opentracing).